# In the movie "Meet the Fockers" does the word "Focker" really sound different?

Tags: pronunciation, offensive-language, minced-oaths

In the movie "Meet the Fockers" does the word "Focker" sound really different from the four-letter word? I don't hear any difference. Do all the actors pronounce this word really differently from native American English speakers?

Comment: We would not confuse them, just like we would not confuse the interjections "ah" and "uh".

Answer (score 14):

The surname "Fokker/Focker" is Dutch in origin. It is a real surname that real people have. It is pronounced /fɒkər/ in English. In these movies the name is not pronounced the same as "fucker" (/fʌkər/). Robert DeNiro and Ben Stiller are both native speakers of New York English and they most certainly distinguish the /ɒ/ (as in "cot") and /ʌ/ (as in "cut") sounds. If you thought it was pronounced the same, you simply mis-heard.

In the original movie in the series, *Meet the Parents*, there was a joke that main character's true name was "Gaylord Focker", which amounts to little more than a throwaway homophobic schoolyard joke based on the similarity (but not identicality) in pronunciation of the name "Focker" and the word "fucker". In the sequels *Meet the Fockers* and *Little Fockers* the joke was mined for more cheap laughs.

It's a joke because they sound *very similar* not because they sound *the same*. It's a pretty lame joke as it is, but if they were pronounced *exactly the same* it wouldn't be a joke at all.

Comment: You only added to my disappointment regarding my listening comprehension. Can you, please, describe what exactly makes these two sounds different. Is it the length of this vowel sound or the position of the jaw. Please, don't refer me to any site that "officially" describes how these sounds must be pronounced - I've been there. What I want is a description from a native speaker on how he feels that difference between those two vowels.

Comment: The distinction is purely one of vowel quality, not length. The /ʌ/ vowel is further front than the /ɒ/ vowel. When I say "Focker" my tongue is pulled back into my throat almost as far back as it can go. For "fucker" the position in the mouth is much more neutral.

Comment: Supposedly, the film-makers were not allowed to use the name "Fockers" unless they could find an actual family with that name. And evidently, they did.

Comment: @Urbycoz almost the opposite; they tried to organise an all-expenses-paid "family reunion" for people of the surname, as a publicity stunt, but couldn't fine many American Fockers. Even when they let Canadian Fockers come too, there were hardly any Fockers interested. It was a bit of a Fock up really.

Comment: The aircraft manufacturer Fokker, from the same surname, made planes for the Germans during WWI. There was a rather splendid interview on British television in the 1990s when a decorated British Airman was describing his battle with a Fokker, how the Fokker came up behind him but he was able to manoeuvre and get the Fokker in his sights before gunning the Fokker down, before the interviewer interrupted to point out that a Fokker was in fact a type of plane.

Comment: Fokker's planes were and still are used in Australia. I heard the tale of an airline (probably MacRobertson Miller) hosting a delegation from Fokker Netherlands and giving them a tour of MMA routes. At the end of the day they ended up in a rough-and-ready mining town in the north of Western Australia (Port Hedland?) and went to the local pub for dinner. The good people from Fokker were amazed. "They're all talking about our planes!" they said.

Answer (score 5):

In American English, the second letter of the *four-letter word* is pronounced /ə/, while in *focker* the second letter is pronounced /ɑ/ (as in *bock*).
In British English, the pronunciation of those vowels is, respectively, /ʌ/ (as in *cup*) and /ɒ/ (as in *hockey*).

Other words with a similar difference are *muck* and *mock*, *duck* and *dock*, *ruck* and *rock*, *buck* and *bock*.

**<sub>[Reference: the *New Oxford American Dictionary*.]</sub>**

Comment: @kiamlaluno - Thank you, but that's not what I was trying to ask about. I know that there should be differences in the correct pronunciation of these words. Here, however, I am asking specifically about how these words were pronounced in that particular movie. The reason I am asking this is because while I can hear the difference between *dock* and *duck* or between *muck* and *mock* I couldn't detect such difference in that movie.

Comment: Well, the actors can pronounce the word differently just to confuse people about the word they are pronouncing. In just another case I would expect an actor's pronunciation to be different from the pronunciation used by "normal" people: when they are imitating the pronunciation used from somebody else (e.g., a person living in a different epoch, a person whose first language is not English).

Comment: FWIW, as a native American English speaker I found *Focker* as pronounced in the movie to be clearly distinct from *fucker*, although the sounds are still similar enough for the joke to be funny. (Well, sort of funny. I didn't think the movies were very good.)

Comment: @JSBangs - Your answer really made me feel very said. It means that I still cannot tell the difference between these two sounds when they are pronounced by native American English speakers. When I first turned on my TV and saw Robert de Niro saying "these Fockers", I really thought he was cursing at that moment (I didn't know the plot yet at that time).

Comment: I feel very sad that you feel very said. **;-)**

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I’m confused by your answer — in the first three-quarters-of-a-sentence, you talk about the *second* vowel in *Focker*/*fucker*, but in the rest of your answer you appear to be talking about the first vowel in these words?  That aside, excellent answer.

Comment: I pronounce the first vowel in "fucker" as /ʌ/ rather than /ə/. The schwa is basically reserved for unstressed syllables.

Comment: I apologize; I started with the idea of writing "the second letter," but I then preferred to write "vowel." I am referring to the second letter of such words.

Comment: The OP asks if the word _focker_ sounds really different from the four-letter word. I took he was referring to the four-letter word written with the _u_. That is the reason I make a comparison with words like _muck_ and _mock_.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the joke relies on the fact, that these words sound similar, although they do not sound the same.
Yesterday I saw an episode of the British sitcom "IT Crowd". There one of the major characters has a date with a guy named Peter File. On several occasions people mix up this name with paedophile.

The root of these kind of jokes is often that people pronounce the word incorrectly and trigger a huge confusion.

Even if the surname Focker is pronounced correctly throughout the movie, when DeNiro discovers his daughters name is going to be Pamela Martha Focker, many people find this funny.